# How can I convert a string which is a list of dictionaries into a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

So I have a string
"[{"type": "add", "qty": "24", "obj": "SPM", "location": "Piedmont Road."}]"
How can I convert this into
just a list of dictionary
[{"type": "add", "qty": "24", "obj": "SPM", "location": "Piedmont Road."}]

I tried `ast.literal_eval` but I got `invalid syntax` error.

EDIT:
I had quotes in my string, removing them and trying `ast.literal_eval` worked pointed out in the comments.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your description and your image of the traceback (which is why we ask for cut-and-pasted text, not images), but are there actually double-quotes at the beginning and ending of your string?  If so, you will have to remove them.  Try `ast.literal_eval(a[1:-1])`.

Comment: You can parse it as Json.
https://pythonexamples.org/python-json-to-list/

Comment: If `ast.literal_eval` didn't like it, then JSON won't like it either.  There is something else going on here.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: ```ast.literal_eval(a[1:-1])``` worked. Thanks @TimRoberts

Answer (score 1):

Is your input always a valid JSON string?  If it is, you can use the standard JSON parser to convert your string into the result you seek:

```
import json

def main():
    inp = '[{"type": "add", "qty": "24", "obj": "SPM", "location": "Piedmont Road."}]'
    print(json.loads(inp))

main()
```

Result:

```
[{'location': 'Piedmont Road.', 'obj': 'SPM', 'qty': '24', 'type': 'add'}]
```

As @Tim points out, if there are quotes at the ends of your string, then just do `json.loads(inp[1:-1])`

Comment: Yeah the quotes were causing the problem. Thanks